# Moving button with image with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI for the first time and am struggling to create a page. In the screenshot provided, I have the button that is supposed to move to another page once pressed which is the green highlighted area, but the red highlighted is where you must click in order to go to the navigation page. I feel like it has something to do with the ZStack but I can't seem to figure it out.

```swift
Button(action: {
                self.isActive = true
            }) {
            ZStack {
                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Group 897")).renderingMode(.original).frame(width: 30, height: 60).padding(.top, 16).offset(x:103, y:-105)
               
            }
         }
```

Basically my question is: How do I make the button trigger move to where the image moved to?

[SwiftUI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvRxg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's caused by your `.offset(x:103, y:-105)`, you change visual position of your button(image of your button), but tappable are still stay on the same place.

Try to position your button with Stack architecture like:

```
VStack {
   HeadingBar() // your heading bar
   HStack { 
     Spacer() // move you button to trailing of screen, then just indent with padding
     Button().padding(.trailing, 10)
   } // end of HStack
   RemainingView() // rest of your page
} // end of VStack
```

If you want to use offset you have to do it like:

```
Button(action: {
                self.isActive = true
            }) {
                Image("yourImage")
            }
            .offset(x:103, y:-105)
```

But the Stack architecture is better for layout, because your app will look similar on all devices..

Answer (score 0):

Realized my mistake. I had to move the offset off the image and to the button.